# I need a Jquery caroussel that support content of different size

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

My problem is quite simple. I need a jquery add-on that will provide me a carousel but this carousel need to support different element size.

Ex: Note the following list contain more tant 3 element but carousel hide them

```
''''''''''   ''''''''''   ''''''''''''''''''    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''  ''''''''  
'previous'   'Element1'   '    Element2    '    '        Element 3        '  ' Next '
''''''''''   ''''''''''   ''''''''''''''''''    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''  ''''''''
```

Something like [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_multiple.html) would be perfect because he works perfectly in all browser execpt for Chrome where he generate me a `Uncaught Error: jCarousel: No width/height set for items. This will cause an infinite loop. Aborting...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact jCarousel support box of deferent size. The problem was that boxes have to be force to be floated and the `ul` item have to be set at a fixed size in the page.

**Note**: The image scroll will be a bit imprecise at the end of the list.